# Element position on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

It's Not working for me.

```
<header id="Header>Heading</header>

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 400){
    $('#Header').css({'background' : '#fff'});
    }{
    $('#Header').css({'background' : ''});`enter code here`
    };
});
```

Give me any suggestion..

Comment: Please describe the exact problem you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400){
    $('#Header').css('background','#fff');
    }else{
    $('#Header').css('background','red');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/37yv9/)**

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes here.

1. You did not specify the `else` keyword
2. 'background' should be 'backgroundColor'
3. Your header tag id field has a quote missing.

   `<header id="Header">Heading</header>`

   `$(window).scroll(function() {
       if (document.body.scrollTop > 400){
          $('#Header').css({'backgroundColor' : '#fff'});
       } else {
          $('#Header').css({'backgroundColor' : 'transparent'});
       };
   });`

Comment: background is OK. He also forgot the closing " for <header id="Header>. Should be <header id="Header">

Comment: Thanks @acarlon I have added this to my answer